# SWIFT value.. has no member

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I am new to swift and am looking for some help with this particular function I am trying to write.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {

        switch identifier {
            case "Show Album":

                let albumViewController = segue.destination as! AlbumViewController
                let albumImageView = (sender as AnyObject).view as! UIImageView
                if let index = index(of: covers, albumImageView) {
                    let album = Album(index: index)
                    albumViewController.album = album
                }
```

On the line:

```
let albumImageView = (sender as AnyObject).view as! UIImageView
```

Getting the error:

```
ambiguous use of 'view'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sender does not have a view because it's of type any so cast the sender to what you're expecting first

Comment: by the way `UIImage` is not a view `UIImageView` is

Comment: @zombie if I cast send as AnyObject it then presents the error of unambiguous use of 'view'

Comment: Still wrong and why don't you get the image from the view look for @IBOutlet and create a connection to the image view

Comment: `sender` is of what type in this scenario?

Comment: AnyObject does not have a property called `view.` 
What you mean to do is cast the sender (which is an Any?) as a UImageView.

This will only succeed if the sender is a UIImageView. Where is the imageView you are referencing?

Answer (score 0):

`sender as AnyObject` casts `sender` to type `AnyObject`. `AnyObject` does not have a property with the name `view`, so calling `.view` on it does not make sense.